# Ajax issue on chrome but not IE, coule be cross domain

Tags: ajax, wordpress, cross-domain

I am working with an ajax all that is giving me a hard time.  I have a wordpress site that has some custom javascript.  I am trying to call a web service to get some data, and I am having a problem with Chrome and Firefox, not IE.  The code is below.  There "errorThrown" variable is not returning an error message, it is just blank. I suspect this may be a cross domain issue due to the fact that I have the wordpress site on port 80, and my service on port 8080.  Thoughts???

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: "http://myServer:8080/myService.svc/GetMyStuff", 
        type:"GET", 
        cache: false,
        success:function(data) { 
            alert("Yeah!!!");   
        }, 
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
            console.log(errorThrown); 
            alert("Error thrown in getProductDefinitions: " + errorThrown + " textStatus: " + textStatus );
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable cors on my web service.  This issue was present only on Chrome and Firefox, there was no issue with IE.  The port number was different, that is what caused the cross domain issue.  Here is the solution that helped me: [WCF Cors](http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html)